# python logic setting variable to none

Tags: python, list, parsing

Ive done enough research to understand my logic (I believe):

I have python code to set a variable to `None` so that at the db level it stores the value of this variable to `Null`.

Logic looks like:

```
# when properly set to something other than `None` an example value might be: ['6.1 ', 'Medium'
thesev=cve.find("span", class_="label-warning").text
thesevcat=re.split("- ", str(thesev))

if thesevcat is None:
    thesevcat=None                    
else:
    #looking to set thesevcat='Medium' for example
    thesevcat=thesevcat[1]
```

sometimes `thesevcat` is successfully parsed the value, othertimes it cant parse it, so I want to set it to `None`

However, I keep getting this error:

```
thesevcat=thesevcat[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

what is going wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Why do you try to `thesevcat=None` if `thesevcat` is already `None`? Did you try `print(thesevcat)` BEFORE indexing into it?

Comment: In your own words, why should `[1]` be a valid index for the list? I see that the code has a special case for a result of `None` from the `re.split`. **Exactly when** do you expect this to happen - under what conditions? Did you **test that**? For example, what do you think will be the result if you try `re.split('- ', '')`? Now, **try it**. What was the result? Do you see how this relates to the problem you are experiencing? I see that you have been on the site for a very long time and ask questions fairly regularly; I should not have to explain basic debugging techniques.

Comment: (Please also think more carefully about variable names, for your own sanity. Words like "the" don't help understand the purpose of the variable. Spelling out words in full, like `severity` (a guess) rather than just `sev`, usually does help.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
thesevcat=thesevcat[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

List index out of range is pretty explicit, it means that if thesevcat is in fact a list (which we don't really know seeing your code but I guess it is), it doesn't have a 2nd index, which means it's a list containing in maximum one element (for instance `["medium"]` )

Please keep in mind that the first index of a list is 0, so if your list is `your_list = ["medium"]`, to access `"medium"`, you need to write `your_list[0]`

if you wanted to access the 2nd element of your list, then your list would need to be at least 2 element long, then you'd access it with the index 1
for instance:

```
your_list = ["medium", "large"]
print(your_list[1])
# would print large
```